# How do I make `android:hint` not take up space when there is text inside the view?

Tags: android, android-edittext, textview

Currently, when you have `android:hint="..."` set on some `AppCompatEditText` or `AppCompatTextView`, the hint will also set an implicit minimum height on something that has `android:height="wrap_content"`.

How would I go about disabling this behavior?

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
    android:paddingTop="12dp"
    android:paddingStart="16dp"
    android:paddingEnd="16dp"
    android:paddingBottom="12dp"

    android:hint="Apparently..."
    android:textColorHint="#BDBDBD"

    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textColor="#000000"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

[image]

Comment: Can you clarify your question a bit? Show to bounds of `Edittext` and expected behaviour .

Comment: You should show us the code of `TextView` you are using.

Comment: @ADM What exactly do you mean by clarification? I thought the pictures did that. Currently (picture #1) I have a hint that is causing `EditText` to extend to 2 lines. When I enter text into the `EditText` it stays at 2 lines even though there is only 1 line of content (picture #2). I want to make it like (picture #3) as if `android:hint` was never there when the `EditText` is non-empty.

Comment: Try to use `min_Width` and `min_height` attributes.

Comment: @ADM That doesn't work

Comment: Ok . Seems like i don't get your question . Never mind .

Comment: @AlanSTACK check my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a workaround for this issue will be to set the `hint` for your `textview/editext` as `""` programatically like this

```
yourTextview.setHint("");
```

you may need to use this only when `yourTextview.getText().toString()` is not `""` so use

```
   if (!yourTextview.getText().toString().equals("")) {
        yourTextview.setHint("");
    }
```

Comment: `yourTextview.getText().toString()` never return `null`.

Comment: use `equals("")` instead